# Getting memory leaks in my iPhone application project how should I resolve it?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leaks in one of the method which I used in my iOS project. I am not able to find out what is happening as I am new in iOS development.

http://screencast.com/t/y2lOtssY2NjO

Comment: You're initializing your UIAlertView twice. It should be [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...] or just [UIAlertView alloc] (without init), then call the designated initializer later (like you're doing it now).

Comment: +1 for a well formatted question. In future make sure that you add the images directly to SO rather than posting it on other sites. If there is any related code please post that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling init twice on your alertView.
I think that makes the issue.

Change that like:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:str message:kAlertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Install now", @"Cancel", nil];
```

Please refer this question : [What happens if i call init more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036569/what-happens-if-i-call-nsobject-init-more-than-once-does-it-increase-retain-cou)

Answer (score 1):

The `static analyser` is pointing out the leak on `UIAlertView` .Initialize the alertView only once.

`UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:str`.....and so on

Comment: Thanks.Leaks has been removed

Answer (score 0):

You can find via instrument here is tutorial  for [click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) that will tell you or Xcode->product->analyze

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but I am not getting proper solution where the leaks actually cause.